# Excel VBA time-formatted combo box

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

What is the best code to create a combobox in a userform to display times as HH:MM AM/PM?

Right now, I have the source for the combobox times as a range of decimal values representing 1-minute increments in worksheet; the formatting of the time is done on a combobox change event (there are 14 comboboxes named in order by number, so it loops through all 14 when the last one is changed).

```
Private Sub COMBOBOX_14_Change()

    Dim i As Integer

        i = 1
        For i = i To 14 Step 1
            INPUT_FORM.Controls("COMBOBOX_" & i) = Format(INPUT_FORM.Controls("COMBOBOX_" & i), "HH:MM AM/PM")

        Next i

        End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful to *see* what you're actually doing. Screenshots **AND** the relevant code would help. I would also suggest not sourcing the combobox items to the sheet/formula.

Comment: Thanks David, I updated the post with code and screenshot.  I appreciate your feedback.  I'm also trying to find a way so that when the user clicks on the combobox arrow, the scroll list starts at the current value and not back at the top of the list.  Do you know how to set that?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more directly focused on formatting the combobox as time, which is a primary issue I have been encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce the problem. I note that you're not using a Format function when assigning the value and that may be what's causing the problem.

I created a userform with a combobox and filled the combobox from 8AM to 5PM in one minute increments. I store the users selection in A1 of Sheet1. When I select 12:00 PM, close and reopen the form, it still shows 12:00. And when I click the dropdown arrow, it starts in the right place.  Maybe you can spot a difference between my code and yours.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    For i = 8 To 17
        For j = 0 To 59
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Format(TimeSerial(i, j, 0), "hh:mm AM/PM")
        Next j
    Next i

    If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("a1").Value) Then
        Me.ComboBox1.Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value, "hh:mm AM/PM")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
```

One important thing to keep in mind is that things in comboboxes are text. Even if they look like number, dates, times, Booleans, etc, it's just text. So while you display it a certain way, always try to do the conversion yourself rather than relying on Excel to do it.

Comment: Dick, thanks for the feedback and the tip on the combobox formatting, I think that will help - I'm going to work on and try again and see if this corrects the issue.  Is the "Me" object name a reference to the "Userform" the private sub code is being applied to?

Comment: Yes, `Me` refers to the class module you're in and Userforms are just special class modules. A lot of people don't use Me (it's the default if you omit it) but I like it for clarity and for the autosuggestion - type `Me.` and get a list of control names (and properties).